# Inject Jenkins Variable to maven using Declarative Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, maven-plugin, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

[image: Want Circled Functionality in Declarative Pipeline Syntax]

I am Unable to add the above circled functionality in attached image as Declarative Pipeline Syntax.
PS I am new to this, i Searched for this on others answers but no one matches my requirements.

For example if there is a Parameter in jenkins named VERSION, maven command should become

```
clean deploy -B -s pathtosettings.xml -DVERSION=valueinparameter
```

Below is my current code
NOte : **I WANT ALL THE PARAMETERS AUTOMATICALLY** -DVERSION=${params.VERSION} doesnt help me

```
 pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Checkout Scm') {
      steps {
        git 'ssh://git@XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.git'
      }
    }

    stage('Maven Build 0') {
      steps {
     
      configFileProvider([configFile(fileId:'0c0631a5-6510-4b4a-833d-4b80fa67d5f3', targetLocation: 'settings.xml', variable: 'SETTINGS_XML')]) {
withMaven{  
 sh "mvn clean deploy -B -s ${SETTINGS_XML}
        }
        }
      }
    }

    
  tools {
    jdk 'JDK_1.8'
  }
  
  
  parameters {
    string(name: 'VERSION', defaultValue: '3_12_0', description: 'version to be in maven')
  }
}
```

Comment: how about `sh 'mvn clean deploy -B -s ${SETTINGS_XML} -DVERSION={VERSION}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 steps {
      script{
          foo= " "
          params.each {param ->
             foo = "${foo} -D${param.key}=${param.value} "
        }
      }
      configFileProvider([configFile(fileId:'XXXX', targetLocation: 'settings.xml', variable: 'SETTINGS_XML')]) {
        withMaven{
            sh "mvn clean deploy -B -s ${SETTINGS_XML} - ${foo}"
        }
      }
```

This is the Only Approach found

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you doesn't need `targetLocation` to perform this.

To access to your parameter value, you need to use `params` prefix.

This is how I'm using the `configFileProvider` to make it work :

```
configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: 'configFileId', variable: 'SETTINGS_XML')]) {
    sh "mvn clean deploy -s \$SETTINGS_XML -B -DVERSION=$params.VERSION"
}
```

With this, the variable which link the settings file is not replaced and it's correctly used in my pipeline and the version is replaced in the command. Don't forget to use a
'Maven settings.xml' type of file in the `configFileProvider`.

Comment: Thanks, but This doesn't adds all the Params in parameters, but i found the solution posted below this.Thanks again.

Comment: Okay I misunderstand the question, your solution should works.